# How to select 1 Row in MySQL Master Table Based on 2 Conditions Existing in a Detailed Table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables -- master and detail

Table A is Master and contains unique rows

```
ID Name
1  Abc
...
7  Def
...
19 Xyz
```

Table B is Detail and contains multiple rows per each master row

```
Ref ID  Desc
1   10  abcdef
1   15  ghijk
1   20  lmnop
...
7   05  qrstu
7   10  vwxyz
7   15  ygfdt
7   20  kjqts
...
19  05  htyge
19  15  gqwes
```

Query Result -- I only wish to select Master Rows that have detailed rows containing both a related detail row of "10" and "15"

So only Rows 1 and Row 7 would be selected.

Thanks for helping.

Here's the shell of my query:

```
$query_string = '
  SELECT a.ID, Name
  FROM table_a AS a
  LEFT JOIN table_b AS b ON b.ref = a.ID
  WHERE b.ID = "10" AND b.ID = "15"
';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.ID, Name
FROM table_a AS a
LEFT JOIN table_b AS b ON b.ref = a.ID
WHERE b.ID IN (10,15)
group by a.ID
having count(distinct b.id) = 2
```